# AutoHotkey On Screen Text

Tags: macros, autohotkey

Trying to figure out how to have an onscreen text appear saying something like "Macro On" when the macro is enabled. Any ideas?

```
macro_on := 0

XButton2::
    macro_on := !macro_on
    if (macro_on)
        SetTimer, DoLoop, -0
    return


DoLoop:
    Loop {
        if (!macro_on)
            break
        Send {e down}   ; Hold key
        Sleep 332       ; Wait
        Send {e up} ; Release key
        Sleep 332       ; Wait
    }
    return
```

Tried just copy and pasting stuff I saw online but I got no clue what I'm doing and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

CoordMode, ToolTip, Screen

macro_on := 0

XButton2::
    macro_on := !macro_on
    if (macro_on)
    {
        ToolTip, Macro On, 0, 0, 1 ; Display ToolTip Nr1 on the top left corner of the screen
        SetTimer, DoLoop, -0
    }
    return


DoLoop:
    Loop {
        if (!macro_on)
        {
            ToolTip,,,, 1  ; Remove that ToolTip
            break
        }
        Send {e down}   ; Hold key
        Sleep 332       ; Wait
        Send {e up} ; Release key
        Sleep 332       ; Wait
    }
    return
```

See [ToolTip](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ToolTip.htm) and [CoordMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/CoordMode.htm).